# how to bind value to hyperlink in gridview in c# code behind

Tags: c#, gridview, binding, hyperlink

I have a custom grid on which i have binded data in my c# code behind. I have given a hyperlink field to one of my column. If i click the hyperlink value, it should navigate to the details page of that hyperlink value. The code is given below,

```
  protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink myLink = new HyperLink();
            myLink.Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
            e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(myLink);
            myLink.NavigateUrl = "Estimation.aspx?EstimateID=" + EstimateID + "&VersionNo=" + VersionNo;
        }
    }
```

If i click the link, the page is getting navigated, but i am not getting the details which are already pre-loaded in that page. Please give me suggestions on how to incorporate this. 
Thanks

Comment: `but i am not getting the details which are already pre-loaded in that page.` Could you please explain in detail.. Which page you are talking about? and what are the pre loaded values?

Comment: could you explain exact behavior of Estimation.aspx page after redirecting to it with query string values EstimateID and VersionNo.

Comment: I think, u need to take care of PageLoad event of Estimation.aspx page. However your question is not fully clear.

Comment: Hi. There is a page called EstimateList where i have the grid and hyperlink column. If i click the link, then it should redirect to the Estimation page where i get the details about the estimates that is created in the previous page.

Comment: So when you click the link, what URL does it navigate to? Does it have the `EstimateID` and `VersionNo` properties populated, or are they missing? The problem is either your code is generating the wrong link, or that link isn't returning what you expect. Which is it?

Comment: When i click the link, it navigates to Estimation.aspx page, which is the right one. But the values are not getting populated. Its not returning any values.

Comment: What is the **exact** URL it is navigating to? Your code gives no indication of how it could be `Estimation.aspx`. It could be `Estimation.aspx?EstimateID=&VersionNo=` or... something else.

Comment: ya. its like Estimation.aspx?EstimateID=0&VersionNo=0. I have lots of estimates. So i wont be able to hard code the estimate and version nos. How should i overcome this? Since  i am a newbie for asp.net and c#, i am feeling difficult.

Comment: @Anu : i have posted solution to your problem check my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to redirect, read [this](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-HyperLink-NavigateUrl-Property.aspx)

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1"   
               runat="server"   
               NavigateUrl="Default2.aspx">  
                 HyperLink  
</asp:HyperLink>
```

to add attribute with link just add

```
HyperLink1.Attributes.Add ("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a small change in the RowDataBound event

myLink.Attributes.Add("href"," your url");

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the values for `EstimateID` and `VersionNo` from the grid row data. Take a look at the documentation for [GridViewRowEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewroweventargs.row.aspx) and you'll see there's a .Row property.

So your code needs to be something like:

```
myLink.NavigateUrl = "Estimation.aspx?EstimateID=" + e.Row.Cells[4].Text + "&VersionNo=" + e.Row.Cells[5].Text;
```

Or, maybe you need to get to the data item associated with the grid row, in which case take a look at e.Row.DataItem, the [GridViewRow.DataItem property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx). This DataItem will need to be cast to the type of data you've bound to the grid in order to fetch the data from it, which might be something like:

```
((MyCustomDataRow)e.Row.DataItem).EstimateID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution :

Page-1 that is your list page :
ASPX code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Data> lstData = new List<Data>();
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        {
            Data objData = new Data();
            objData.EstimateID = index;
            objData.VersionNo = "VersionNo" + index;
            lstData.Add(objData);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = lstData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int EstimateID { get; set; }
        public string VersionNo { get; set; }
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink HyperLink1 = e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1") as HyperLink;
            HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Details.aspx?EstimateID=" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "&VersionNo=" + e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
        }
    }
```

Page-2 that is your details page :
Code behind :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(Request.QueryString["EstimateID"].ToString());
        Response.Write(Request.QueryString["VersionNo"].ToString());
    }
```